# Read Excel file in C++ J2ME and get data from itQ

Tags: c++, excel

How can I open an *Excel* file in C++ J2ME and get data from it or store data in it?
This is my (miniscule) approach so far:

```
#include <fstream>
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("customer.dat");
```

Comment: [C++ ADO Connection](//stackoverflow.com/q/47224404)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
ofstream filestore("customer.dat"); //store data in file
string data1; //store text
int data2;    //store integers
cout<<"enter data or press ctrl+z to quit \n";
while(cin>>data1>>data2){
    filestore<<data1<<endl;
    filestore<<data2<<endl;
}
ifstream fileread("customer.dat");//read data from file
string info1;
int info2;
while(fileread>>info1>>info2){
    cout<<info1<<"  "<<info2<<endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.